# Organize level users with MongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm modeling a database to save agricultural data. I have some users types on my application, like partners (companies and cooperatives) and farmers. The partners have a specific access control and the farmers other access control only to see your data.

My question is: How Can I do these model using mongoose schema? It's interesting insert all users types in a unique schema?

Sorry, but I'm thinking in a tabular model with a separate table for each user type.

Thanks

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqA3M.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [enum option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) in defining your schema.

```
var ROLES = ["farmer", "partner"]

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ROLES
    }
});
```

This will give users a role, but validates that it can only be one of those two roles when creating and saving the user. Any way you do it, the role based logic is still up to you. This just allows you to have the rest of the fields of the schema be the same. If each role is going to have different keys, then different collections are more practical. If they will both be using `name` and `location` and whatever other keys you have, then keeping them the same collection makes more sense.